# Update column in mysql with trigger

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML table where I get printed out rows from a MySQL database. To the right of each HTML row I have a button where I can click Select. If I click that button I need a function that updates the MySQL column name "records" with + 1.

Because it is quite new to me, I would like to try and start a little bit structured on the proces. So I am trying to make my first trigger. I have a table called `football`. I use `after` because the data is inserted. I insert into records and + 1 on the old value.

Am I on the right track of doing what I want, or is this totally beside?

```
DELIMITER$$
    CREATE TRIGGER recordUpdate
    AFTER UPDATE ON football
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO football(records) VALUES(OLD.records + 1);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why do you feel you need a trigger when you say that *"If I click that button I need a function that updates the MySQL column name "records" with + 1."* ? I feel that am not grasping the question here. A regular UPDATE with a WHERE clause will do. An INSERT will overwrite your db, unless that's what you want.

Comment: triggers in the DBMS are fired on events like update, delete, insert … so maybe the wrong approach for you here

Comment: Hm okay. Then I will try that instead :-) Just thought it would be a good practice, but I will wait with that. So the query is something like: `UPDATE football SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = ##?##;` ?. Each row have an id as a primary key. How can I set that Id, so I am updating on the correct row where I have the select button?

Comment: What your trigger does right now: In case a row in your (mysql-)table is updated (means changed) it inserts another new row where the value in the column records is one higher than the value of the column records of the updated row. Maybe you could show the part where the row is updated from php-side so one can grasp your intent in this ... at first glance your html-table has nothing to do with mysql yet.

Comment: @Fuzzzzel: I will skip that thought and making an UPDATE query instead.

Comment: Still I don't see the connection between your HTML and mysql. There must be some HTML-markup that shows the table/form and a PHP-file that receives the browser's request to actually initiate your mysql command. That part might illustrate your question a little.

Comment: Thank you to all of the comments. I will try to code it from here, so I also learn something.

Comment: `UPDATE football SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = $id_pulled_from_form_element_integer;` - *"How can I set that Id, so I am updating on the correct row where I have the select button?"* - You basically answered your own question, and as to how to set a button for each one, you'd need a form with a named hidden element and a value pulled from a SELECT query with a WHERE clause @Mimi all inside a loop, fetched from successful results and using a prepared statement if user interaction is involved.

Comment: I print the button with the id like this: `<div class="btn btn-warning btn-open-modal" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">See Details '.'</div>.` So maybe the query is something like: `UPDATE football SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = $row['id'];`

Comment: @Mimi what would you like to do with the question, delete it or for me to convert my comments to an answer to close the question? I can make it a community wiki also; I don't want rep from this. However, I can't write out a full solution though. What I've told you in my comment to you is the basic storyboard on how to do this. Ping me back if you want, *cheers*

Comment: `UPDATE football SET records = records + 1 WHERE id = $row['id'];` - that might not work, you'd need to assign a variable to the `$row['id']` first. As in `$id = $row['id'];` then using that in the WHERE clause.